# Jobs RSS feed with tags returns non tagged results

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have an RSS feed for jobs with Clojure. I'd set it up previously with https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?tags=clojure. The web version of this is https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&tags=clojure. This used to work well, but now it returns a bunch of results that aren't tagged with Clojure.

It seems like the search query syntax has changed, as now https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&searchTerm=clojure seems to return what I'm after? It seems like tag search isn't working correctly?